# List of folders that have IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, acl

I would like to have a PowerShell commands that will give a list of folders that have  `IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users`

I have tried this command:

```
Get-Acl -Path "\\nasaunr\DEPARTMENTS\*" | Select -ExpandProperty Access
```

But it provides only the  `BUILTIN\Users` , not the *folder names*. 
I needed all folders inside this folder  `\\nasaunr\DEPARTMENTS\*`

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Directory` and `-Recurse` switch to retrieve all directories recursively. Then you can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the IdentityReference:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\nasaunr\DEPARTMENTS\' -Directory -Recurse | 
    Where { ( $_ | get-acl | select -expand Access | select -expand IdentityReference) -contains 'BUILTIN\Users' }
```

Comment: thanks Martin , i am using it. :) thank you for reading my post and answering.

Comment: Since your code already requires PowerShell v3 (that's when the `-Directory` switch was introduced) you could simplify the `Where-Object` clause as well: `(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access.IdentityReference -contains 'BUILTIN\Users'`